# Can I return a mapped object from a GraphQL query?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm wondering if I can create an object using GraphQL, instead of manipulating the data that GraphQL returns. I'm using GraphQL in Gatsby.

My query looks something like this:

```
nodes {
  name
  url
}
```

The data looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "nodes": [
      {
        "name": "ABC"
        "url": "ABC.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is it possible to use GraphQL to return something that looks like this?

```
{
   "data": {
      "ABC": "ABC.com"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am missing the context of your use case, but I question why you would need this functionality.

The typical use case would be to hydrate the **data** object with the property name and value as key value pairs, which will allow you to access the data in your JSX template as **data.propertyname**.

If you change the structure to what you are suggesting above, you would need to know the "name" of the object when trying to access it in the context of the **data** object.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Yeah in this case I already have the "name" of the object from a different dataset. So I'm creating the object I need using `.reduce` in the JS, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it straight from GraphQL.

Comment: Considering your use case, this link may be helpful: https://github.com/APIs-guru/graphql-lodash.  This, however, is experimental and limited in use.  Typically, you will be constrained by the schema of the GraphQL endpoint.